# How to redirect stdout & stdin to telnet?

Tags: pipe, telnet

I am working on embedded product running Linux. The device uses  /dev/ttyO0 as console. On boot is automatically start a program with which uses input from /dev/ttyO0 (serial), and gives some information on device status on the serial. I want to redirect /dev/ttyO0 to something I can reach through the network (such as ssh).

I am able to connect by telnet, but I don't see any of the information seen in serial. What can I do for this purpose ?

Comment: By “stdout”, you mean the standard output of a program, right?

Comment: yes, I do. I have edited the question, can you remove the on hold ?

Comment: You say you mean the output of a program, but then you've edited to say that data is coming from a serial connection. Which one is it? Please describe the flow of data. Don't just say “input” or “output”, because it isn't clear what this is the input and output of. Tell us what produces the data and what connections it goes over (e.g. a device emits data on a serial line, the data is received by the computer and needs to be forwarded over a TCP connection to a program listening on another machine, and in the other direction etc.)

Comment: Hi Giles, I've edited it again, I think it is clearer now. Thx

Comment: To me it is still unclear what you want. My guess is: The device uses /dev/ttyO0 as the console, and you want to see the console. Thus you want to redirect all data that goes to /dev/ttyO0 to something you can reach through the network (such as ssh).

Comment: Hi, Is it OK now ? Thx, Ran

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You don't. Use netcat `nc` instead. It will do what you want, whereas `telnet` will not.

```
(echo helo ole.tange.dk;
 echo mail from: '<spam@tange.dk>';
 echo rcpt to: '<spam@tange.dk>';
 echo data;
 echo Subject: This is an email;
 echo;
 echo test;
 echo .;
 echo quit) | nc smtp.server.example.com 25 | grep 250
```

Comment: Hi Ole, do you mean it is not possible by connecting with telnet? How do you use nc to redirect stdout to the netcat utility ?

Comment: What I mean is that I have spent a tremendous amount of time trying to get telnet to behave and have failed. netcat on the other hand worked in first try: echo foo | nc server 23

Comment: thanks! I also see the following example as an option: nc www.example.com port < /dev/ttyS0

Comment: but still I will need to write the above option from the serial interface, right ?

Comment: I have not tested it, but it looks about right, yes.

Comment: Hi Ole, one more... doing  echo foo | nc server, should be done from serial , right ?

Comment: What about stdin ? can it also be redirected to netcat ?

Comment: I am ashamed I have been using Unix/Linux for so long and never new about this utility (netcat)... Excellent!

Comment: Doesn't work with mailhog: `Received 114 bytes: 'helo ole.tange.dk\nmail from: <spam@tange.dk>\nrcpt to: <spam@tange.dk>\ndata\nSubject: This is an email\n\ntest\n.\nquit\n'`

Comment: @Eric Try using \r\n instead of \n.

Comment: @OleTange I'm pointing out that your solution to the problem doesn't work in all cases and hence the "answer" you've posted needs to be updated so it always works... if you think you've found a way to always make it work then fine, update your "answer" accordingly and I may check it out later. Thank you

Comment: @Eric To be fair, that's a problem with using the SMTP protocol, not anything to do with `nc`.

Comment: Not at all, it's a problem with your answer: you use CR in your answer and when I pointed out it doesn't work you said it's because one should use CRLF instead. Then you continue explaining that the protocol is not compatible with your answer... so update your bloody answer and stop saying it's not your fault, that you're doing everything great for f**k sake. The internet is filled of people full of themselves.

Answer (score 3):

If you would like to redirect the output to telnet, here is an example:

```
(
echo "helo mailhub";
sleep 1;
echo "mail from:<root>";
sleep 1;
echo "rcpt to:<root>";
sleep 1;
echo "data";
sleep 1;
echo "[...]";
echo ".";
sleep 2;
) | telnet mailserver 25
```

HTH

Comment: Hi Scyld, I've edited my question, I actually need both stdin and stdout. Thx